# Stacking switch statements c++

Tags: c++

I am just wondering if we can stack switch case statements such as, a case leading to another case into another case and so on. I am currently planning on how to make my project but i need to confirm whether that is possible or not

Comment: Use code to explain what you mean.

Comment: Cases can fall through to the next one down if you leave out the `break;` and you can embed one switch inside the case of another.

Comment: [Did you try it?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) What happened? If you share your code with us we may be able to help you fix it.

Comment: Nested `switch...case` constructs are legal, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Does your project hinge on whether this is possible or not?

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm going to add a fun way to do it.

Warning: I wouldn't actually ever do this, it is just a way to do what you like.

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    int foo = 0;
    switch ( foo ) 
    {
    case 0 :
        goto that;
        break;
    case 1 :
that :
        std::cout << 'b';
        goto theOther; 
        break;
    case 2 :
theOther :
        std::cout << 'a';
        goto andAnother;
        break;
    case 3 :
andAnother :
        std::cout << 'r';
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can't "stack" them freely. In C++ if you remove the break statements it will "fall through". For example this will give the same result...

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    int foo = 0;
    switch ( foo ) 
    {
    case 0 :
    case 1 :
        std::cout << 'b';
    case 2 :
        std::cout << 'a';
    case 3 :
        std::cout << 'r';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What the former would allow you to do is...

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    int foo = 0;
    switch ( foo ) 
    {
    case 0 :
        goto andAnother; 
        break;
    case 1 :
that :
        std::cout << 'b'; 
        break;
    case 2 :
theOther :
        std::cout << 'a';
        goto that;
        break;
    case 3 :
andAnother :
        std::cout << 'r';
        goto theOther;
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should never do that for something serious. I agree. But that looks too fun not to try. Kudos.